# Item assignment in the object does not affect Json serializer response

Tags: python, django, django-views

In my index view, I am assigning a new item in my `all_albums` object.

The item is assigned correctly to the All_albums object but it is no shown in the JSON output.

```
def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()

    for alb in all_albums:
        if alb.album_title == "Let It Be":
            alb.new= "-> Item assignmen successsss"

    response = serializers.serialize("json", all_albums)

    return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build in django serializers does not serializer extra attribute.

1. Either you need to customize built in serializers located in django.core

```py
#from django.core import serializers
```

2. You loop through response data and assign value. First you need to convert to json format for respon

```py
import json
response = serializers.serialize("json", all_albums)
response = json.loads(response)
# then you can check and assing new value by looping and checking
```

3. It you want simplicity, you can you djangorestframework ModelSerializer. Offcourse you need to install 
   [More detail on django rest framework serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

```py
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
class CustomAlbumSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = '__all__'
        def to_representation(self, instance):
            ret = super().to_representation(instance)
            if instance.album_title == "Let It Be":
                ret['new'] = 'new item'
         return ret


def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    response = CustomAlbumSerializer(all_albums, many=True).data
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

You can use **setattr** some thing like this.

```py
# setattr(instance, attribute, value)
for alb in all_albums:
    if alb.album_title == "Let It Be":
       setattr(alb, 'new','new item')
```

```
OR
```

```py
for alb in all_albums:
    if alb.album_title == "Let It Be":
       alb.new = "new item
```

Comment: The issue, when i use `response = serializers.serialize("json", all_albums)` it does not return the new item

Comment: please check some alternatives

Comment: I believe, a simpler solution would be to output the object as json without serializing it?

Comment: CustomAlbumSerializer will serializer your querysets

Comment: i think there is something called `json.dumps()` I think it's like json_encode in 

Comment: you should use json.loads as i have stated in 2 and process accordingly

Comment: Wha is `data`? on `response = json.loads(data)`

Comment: sorry in this case data is response

Comment: getting parse error on line 1 see https://i.imgur.com/ehHHvcz.png